# Update listitem in document library without using eventreceivers

Tags: document-library, sub-site, updatelistitems

How to update a listitems say status column in my document library from `Pending` to `Approved` without using event receivers or C#?

If I use SPServices , it needs to be added as content editor web part code / separate js function in  master page.

My issue is, I can't use this approach as I am creating sub sites/doc libs automatically on a button click event of my visual web part.

Here, end user will use the default UI form for updating the list items.

Any other approaches available?

Comment: when you want your Status column to change from Pending to Approved? Do you want this update on your site/library creation?

Comment: No. when end user adds an item into the document library, i need to update the column value to pending with approver1 and when approver1  approved, i want to changed to approved by approver1 ...am not using sp d 2013 WF manager . am tryng to find out a non-managed/ non-c# ,  non-wsp solution

Comment: What do you mean by SPD 2013 WF manager? It should be either SPD 2013 workflow or SP 2013 WF manager. SPD 2013 WF is your no-code logic with rules and conditions whereas SP 2013 WF Manager is the new workflow management.

Comment: My mistake, i mean to say SP 2013 WF Manager.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not load JS code in the (Master)Page, JSLink, or Custom Actions...

Then place the code inside the ListItem with [JavaScript in a Calculated Column](https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How),

Here are some examples to get you started: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/Create/

***I adapted one of the top of my head, have NOT tested it***

in a View (and a View only!) this Calculated Column Formula will display a Button for each ListItem

```
="<button onclick=""{event.stopPropagation();"
 & "    var context=new SP.ClientContext.get_current();"
 & "    var list=context.get_web().get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());"
 & "    var item=list.getItemById( GetAncestor(this,'TR').id.split(',')[1] );"
 & "    context.load(item);"
 & "    item.set_item('Status', 'Approved');"
 & "    item.update();"
 & "    context.executeQueryAsync("
 & "     Function.createDelegate(this, function(){"
 & "        AJAXRefreshView({currentCtx:ctx,csrAjaxRefresh:true},1);"
 & "     }));"
 & "    }"">Approve</button>"
```

**Disclaimer:**
It is a PITA to debug Calculated Columns. Because you don't get feedback until you save a Formula (with an undescriptive message) and you end up having to click multiple times to get back to your Formula.

I have written a small 'CalcMaster' bookmarklet which hooks into the formula-editor and does a save of the Formula on every keypress; giving immediate feedback.

https://github.com/Danny-Engelman/CalcMaster

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by creating a simple SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow and a custom column "Status".

- First enable Content Approval in your document library through Library Settings > Versioning Settings. Detail steps given in this [ARTICLE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-a-site-list-or-library-to-require-approval-of-items-or-files-7f765a32-741d-4314-b27f-9b785437518c#__toc258597260).
- Create a custom choice column `Status` and provide two values - **Pending** and **Approved**. Make **Pending** as the default value. This will meet your need when a user adds a document to library the `Status` column value will be updated as **Pending** automatically.
- Open SPD 2013 and create a list workflow on your document library.
- Just insert below two steps and you are done. Save and publish the workflow. Ensure you select "*Start workflow when an item is changed*" at the Start Options.

The workflow checks if the document is approved via Content Approval and if it is approved then your `Status` column value is changed to **Approved**.

[image]

Comment: you have told, create a list workflow.By default, its a sp 2010approval 2010 workflow  will be selected?So in this case, when i tried with am not getting the result as you mentioned.

Comment: There is an out of the box approval workflow and there is another SharePoint designer workflow. You must open your SharePoint Designer and create a list workflow and associate it to your document library. Check this http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/227/How-to-create-a-simple-List-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-SharePoint-2010.html, it should guide you on creating a list workflow.